# SFML combine drawable objects

Tags: c++, sfml

I want to combine let's say sf:RectangleShape and sf::Text into one drawable object so that I only have to call the function mWindow.draw() once for the two objects. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is implement a class which inherits from `sf::Drawable`, and override the `draw` function to draw both your rectangle and your text. Your render window will take care of the rest.

```
class BoxAndText : public sf::Drawable
{
public:
    sf::RectangleShape rect;
    sf::Text text;
private:
    void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const override
    {
        target.draw(rect, states);
        target.draw(text, states);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But how do I use the function then? target.draw(window)?

Comment: @NotImportant: You don't call this function directly. It is utilized by `sf::RenderWindow::draw`. So you create a `BoxAndText` object, then you call `mWindow.draw(object)`, just like you would with any other drawable (exactly the syntax you were requesting).